# Convert function view to class based view

Tags: django

I am trying to write a a Function-based View (FBV) as a Class-based View (CBV), specifically a CreateView. So far I have been able to write the FBV as a generic View but not as a CreateView. How would I go about doing this?

**FBV**

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'accounts/registration.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'registered':registered})
```

**Converted View**

```
class RegisterView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        registered = False
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request,'accounts/registration.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'registered':registered})

    def post(self, request):
        registered = False
        user_form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
        return render(request,'accounts/registration.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'registered':registered})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may follow it

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/registration.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        registered = False
        user_form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
        return render(request,'accounts/registration.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'registered':registered})
```